# Can I pass an auth token parameter in a WebhookResponse and use the token in the webhook header?

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

[Take token from response and add here for authorization header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfFTJ.png)

As the title suggests, I'd like to pass a bearer token. However, each token is unique to a user so I cannot pass a static token. Is there a way to accomplish this without using google cloud services, only using the standard dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're passing the information something like this:

`client (sends bearer token in parameters) -> Dialogflow -> fulfillment`

and you'd like to send it from Dialogflow -> webhook using the "Authorization" HTTP header.

This isn't directly possible.

What you can do, however, is something like this:

`client (sends bearer token in context parameters) -> Dialogflow -> proxy -> fulfillment`

In this case, the proxy would be a thin webhook that takes the bearer token from the parameter and uses it as the auth header for the call to the fulfillment webhook. The request itself (from Dialogflow to proxy) would be echoed to the fulfillment webhook, and the response (from fulfillment to proxy) would also be relayed.